# using angular $resource properly

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code:

```
var dbDelivery = Deliveries.get({deliveryId: delivery.id}, function() {
                if (!dbDelivery.id) {
                    toaster.pop('error', 'Error', 'That delivery does not exist. Somebody else may have deleted it.');
                    var deliveryIndex = $rootScope._.findIndex($scope.deliveries, 'id', delivery.id);
                    $scope.deliveries.splice(deliveryIndex, 1);
                    return;
                }
                dbDelivery.confirmed = true;
                dbDelivery.$update(function() { delivery.confirmed = true; }, ServerErrorAlert);
                return dbDelivery.$promise;
            })
```

Questions:
1) What happens if one calls multiple resource methods on a resource and returns the $promise? Does it just depend on the last method executed?
2) What is $resource looking for in order to reject the promise? I mean does it just depend on the response status code? If so which status codes result in a success and which result in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can chain promises, but every $resource method call generate a new promise that represent the called method promise

2) It resolve the promise if the http response code is a success code 2xx ([see](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

Comment: So in the code in the original post does the $promise get resolved after the $update method is successful? does the get method have any affect on the promise given the point at which it is called?

Comment: No, your code isn't a promise chain (see [Chainig promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). The $update is in the success callback function and is called after the $resourse resolve the http  get